# Button click in polymer dart does not work; needs polymer-element

Tags: dart, polymer

I am creating my first polymer application/example and a simple `button on-click` is not working. The method is not called. I would like to use a simple button without creating a new polymer-element (the commented code). If I use the buttons in the polymer-element, they just work fine.

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Button</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
     <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Button</h1>

   <template id="tmpl" bind>
     <button  on-click="myMethod">Click me!</button><!! DOES NOT WORK!!! -->
     </template> 
     <!--
   <polymer-element name="my-element" extends="div">
      <template>
        <p>
          <button on-click="myMethod">Show Message</button>
          <button on-click="myMethod">Hide Message</button>
        </p>
      </template>   
    </polymer-element>

    <my-element id="test"></my-element>-->

    <script type="application/dart" src="button.dart"></script>       
  </body>
</html>
```

.

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

void main() {
  query("#tmpl").model = new MyClass();
}

@CustomTag('my-element')
class MyClass extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin{

  @observable String name="testname";

  void myMethod(var e, var detail, var target) {
    print("button works");
  }
}
```

Edit: I just realised that `myMethod` called by my button from the polymer-element has no access to the data of other elements defined (e.g. radio buttons or checkboxes) in the template `tmpl`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `on-*` attributes only work from within Polymer elements.

Comment: Ok, but how do I share data or application states between different polymer-elements? If polymer-element1 changes some initializationvalue from x to z, the polymer-element2 reads again only x.

Comment: Message passing is a good way to do this. Firing events and/or responding to property changes. http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom element dart-button and use a custom attribute to set the onclick method.
[As I used it in this demo for onblur](https://github.com/zoechi/dart-polymer-dart-examples/commit/39567d11bb09935d43445e2f38539f87d6df5c05)

You can share a model between the controls which should cooperate and hold the controls states in this model.
Then you have access to the other controls state.