# Dart passing data to a dynamically created polymer element

Tags: parameter-passing, dart, dart-polymer

I have read this thread about how to pass data to a polymer element 
[Button click in polymer dart does not work; needs polymer-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553448/button-click-in-polymer-dart-does-not-work-needs-polymer-element)

But however, if I want to pass data to a programmatically created element by using createElement() in polymer.dart, there's no wrapping template. How am I going to pass the data as mentioned above?

Btw, even though I think dart is a really cool language (I dislike JavaScript,) I found polymer in dart maybe still not ready yet. A lot of things are not documented and have to go though examples or ask here.

Thanks,
Yi

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the start()-function from MyElementElement-class and add it to upper level. Basically you shouldn't have any reference in custom-element to upper level objects. Now the custom element is not reuseable, it works only within this context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example on how i passed data to a dynamically created custom polymer-element.
My intention was, click on an "a href" and load a polymer-element in a container div.

polymer_element.html

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template bind>
    <p> {{ mytext }} </p>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="polymer_myelement.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

polymor_element.dart

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:custom_element/custom_element.dart';

@CustomTag('polymer-myelement')
class MyElementElement extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {

  bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;

  @observable String mytext = "initial text";

  void start() {

    query('#a href to click').onClick.listen((MouseEvent event){
      query('.container').children.clear();
      var myElem = createElement('polymer-myelement');

      MyElementElement myel = myElem.xtag;
      myel.mytext = "i changed the text now or import w/e you want";

      query('.container').children.add(myElem);

    });    
  }
}

main() {
  MyElementElement el = new MyElementElement();
  el.start();
}
```

index.html

```dart
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer_myelement.html">
  and everything you need ...
</head>
<body>
  <a href to click>click me for new text</a>
  <div class="container">
  <!-- START OF MAINCONTAINER -->

  <!-- END OF MAINCONTAINER -->
  </div>
</body>
```

So here is the explanation:
In my main() i just run my start() function and set an onclickListener for my navigation bar  href. When i click my href now, i just clear all children in my "div class="container", because i always want a clear div before i insert my polymer-elements. 
Now create a polymer-Element with "createElement('polymer-mylement');".
Create a MyElement object and assign the polymer-element "xtag" to it.
Now you have access to all the properties and can change them.
Just add your created Element to your div and you are done.

You just dynamically created a polymer-element, assigned your new data to it and see it in your index.html

Comment: Thanks. It does work. I'm curious that does it document anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for a long time but anything work. Only one solution work fine for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20067111/189411